# finding pairs from the list whose sum is even

Tags: python, list

i need to find pairs from a list whose sum when added is even number
example: `list=[1,4,3,2,5,6,7]`
`paired_list=[(1,3),(1,5),(1,7),(4,2),(4,6),(3,5),(3,7)..and so on]`
the pairs should not repeat.
1+3=4 is even
(1+5)=6 is even

Answer (score 3):

Use itertools to generate combinations and apply the logic.

```
from itertools import combinations
l1=[1,4,3,2,5,6,7]

comb=[ i for i in  combinations(l1,2) if sum(i)%2==0]

print (comb)
```

Comment: you can just use `sum(i) % 2`, i.e. `comb = [item for item in combinations(l1,2) if not sum(item) % 2]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension with conditions to make sure the sum is even, i.e. the remainder equals zero after dividing the sum by 2:

```
[(i,j) for i in lst for j in lst if i != j and (i+j)%2 == 0]
```

Output:

```
[(1, 3),
 (1, 5),
 (1, 7),
 (4, 2),
 (4, 6),
 (3, 1),
 (3, 5),
 (3, 7),
 (2, 4),
 (2, 6),
 (5, 1),
 (5, 3),
 (5, 7),
 (6, 4),
 (6, 2),
 (7, 1),
 (7, 3),
 (7, 5)]
```

Comment: why so complicated check condition (up to 4 modulo calculations) , when you can just check the sum?

Comment: Thanks @buran -- overthinking it a little.

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through the elements and check the sum

```
list=list(set([1,4,3,2,5,6,7]))

output_list = []
for i in list:
    for j in range(i+1, len(list), 1):
        if (i + list[j]) % 2 == 0:
            output_list.append([i, list[j]])

print(output_list)
```

Output

```
[[1, 3], [1, 5], [1, 7], [2, 4], [2, 6], [3, 5], [3, 7], [4, 6], [5, 7]]
```